# Android Unknown Application Crash

Tags: android, android-manifest, jakarta-mail

I am trying to make an email client, whenever I try to run the application  it crashes with the default message. Can any one please tell me where I am going wrong. Below are my Java files and manifest .

EmailManager.java

```
public class EmailManager {



    private String stmpHost = "smtp.gmail.com";
        private String mailServer = "imap.gmail.com";
        private EmailAccount account;
        private Session smtpSession; 
        private Session imapSession; 
        private Folder inbox;
        private Store store;



        public EmailManager(String username, String password, String urlServer, String stmpHost, String mailServer) {
            account = new EmailAccount(username, password, urlServer);
            this.stmpHost = stmpHost;
            this.mailServer = mailServer;
            initProtocol();
        }
        private void initProtocol() {
            EmailAuthenticator authenticator = new EmailAuthenticator(account);

            Properties props1 = new Properties();  
            props1.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtps");  
            props1.setProperty("mail.host", stmpHost);  
            props1.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");  
            props1.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");  
            props1.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");  
            props1.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");  
            props1.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");  
            props1.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");  
            smtpSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props1, authenticator); 

            Properties props2 = new Properties();
            props2.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
            props2.setProperty("mail.imaps.host", mailServer);
            props2.setProperty("mail.imaps.port", "993");
            props2.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
            props2.setProperty("mail.imaps.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
            imapSession = Session.getInstance(props2);
        }   
        public Message[] getMails() throws MessagingException {
            store = imapSession.getStore("imaps");
            store.connect(mailServer, account.username, account.password);
            inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
            Message[] result = inbox.getMessages();

            for (int i=0, n=result.length; i<n; i++) {
                   System.out.println(i + ": " + result[i].getFrom()[0] 
                     + "\t" + result[i].getSubject());


        }
            return result;
        }   
        public void close() {
            //Close connection 
            try {
                inbox.close(false);
                store.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }       
        }
        public synchronized void sendMail(String subject, String body, String sender, String recipients) throws Exception {  
            MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(smtpSession);
            DataHandler handler = new DataHandler(new ByteArrayDataSource(body.getBytes(), "text/plain"));  
            message.setSender(new InternetAddress(sender));  
            message.setSubject(subject);  
            message.setDataHandler(handler);  
            if (recipients.indexOf(',') > 0)  
                message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(recipients));  
            else  
                message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(recipients));  
            Transport.send(message);  


            }
        }
```

this email manager is called in mainactivity.java to run it

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, EmailManager.class));
    } 

}
```

Below is my Android manifest file.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.mailtest.android"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".EmailManager"
                  android:label="@string/app_name" android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".EmailAithenticator"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".EmailAccount"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ByteArrayDataSource"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

The Log Cat had  the following errors in red:

> 07-08 07:03:03.947: DEBUG/WifiService(1329): enable and start wifi due to updateWifiState
>   07-08 07:54:34.047: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454): getInputStream failed! https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/276968_73855584817_8241940_q.jpg
>   07-08 07:54:34.047: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454): java.net.UnknownHostException: fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net
>   07-08 07:54:34.047: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:500)
>   07-08 07:54:34.047: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:297)
>   07-08 07:54:34.047: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:256)
>   07-08 07:54:34.047: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
>   07-08 07:54:34.047: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
>   07-08 07:54:34.047: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
>   07-08 07:54:34.047: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
>   07-08 07:54:34.047: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
>   07-08 07:54:34.047: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
>   07-08 07:54:34.047: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
>   07-08 07:54:34.047: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454):     at com.htc.graphics.drawable.UrlDrawable.getInputStream(UrlDrawable.java:956)
>   07-08 07:54:34.047: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454):     at com.htc.graphics.drawable.UrlDrawable.getFromRemote(UrlDrawable.java:983)
>   07-08 07:54:34.047: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454):     at com.htc.graphics.drawable.UrlDrawable.access$800(UrlDrawable.java:71)
>   07-08 07:54:34.047: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454):     at com.htc.graphics.drawable.UrlDrawable$WorkerCallable.call(UrlDrawable.java:776)
>   07-08 07:54:34.047: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454):     at com.htc.graphics.drawable.UrlDrawable$WorkerCallable.call(UrlDrawable.java:710)
>   07-08 07:54:34.047: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
>   07-08 07:54:34.047: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>   07-08 07:54:34.047: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
>   07-08 07:54:34.047: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
>   07-08 07:54:34.047: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1027)
>   07-08 07:54:34.057: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454): getInputStream failed! https://fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net/hprofile-ak-snc4/276968_73855584817_8241940_q.jpg
>   07-08 07:54:34.057: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454): java.net.UnknownHostException: fbcdn-profile-a.akamaihd.net
>   07-08 07:54:34.057: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:500)
>   07-08 07:54:34.057: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:297)
>   07-08 07:54:34.057: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:256)
>   07-08 07:54:34.057: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:136)
>   07-08 07:54:34.057: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
>   07-08 07:54:34.057: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
>   07-08 07:54:34.057: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
>   07-08 07:54:34.057: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
>   07-08 07:54:34.057: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
>   07-08 07:54:34.057: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
>   07-08 07:54:34.057: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454):     at com.htc.graphics.drawable.UrlDrawable.getInputStream(UrlDrawable.java:956)
>   07-08 07:54:34.057: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454):     at com.htc.graphics.drawable.UrlDrawable.getFromRemote(UrlDrawable.java:984)
>   07-08 07:54:34.057: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454):     at com.htc.graphics.drawable.UrlDrawable.access$800(UrlDrawable.java:71)
>   07-08 07:54:34.057: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454):     at com.htc.graphics.drawable.UrlDrawable$WorkerCallable.call(UrlDrawable.java:776)
>   07-08 07:54:34.057: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454):     at com.htc.graphics.drawable.UrlDrawable$WorkerCallable.call(UrlDrawable.java:710)
>   07-08 07:54:34.057: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
>   07-08 07:54:34.057: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
>   07-08 07:54:34.057: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
>   07-08 07:54:34.057: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
>   07-08 07:54:34.057: ERROR/UrlDrawable(1454):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1027)
>   07-08 07:55:32.157: WARN/ResourceType(1537): Failure getting entry for 0x7f02027e (t=1 e=638) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
>   07-08 07:55:32.157: WARN/ResourceType(1537): getEntry failing because entryIndex 335 is beyond type entryCount 123
>   07-08 07:55:32.157: WARN/ResourceType(1537): Failure getting entry for 0x7f02014f (t=1 e=335) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
>   07-08 07:55:32.167: WARN/ResourceType(1537): getEntry failing because entryIndex 187 is beyond type entryCount 123
>   07-08 07:55:32.167: WARN/ResourceType(1537): Failure getting entry for 0x7f0200bb (t=1 e=187) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
>   07-08 07:55:32.177: WARN/ResourceType(1537): getEntry failing because entryIndex 638 is beyond type entryCount 123
>   07-08 07:55:32.177: WARN/ResourceType(1537): Failure getting entry for 0x7f02027e (t=1 e=638) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
>   07-08 07:55:32.177: WARN/ResourceType(1537): getEntry failing because entryIndex 335 is beyond type entryCount 123
>   07-08 07:55:32.177: WARN/ResourceType(1537): Failure getting entry for 0x7f02014f (t=1 e=335) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
>   07-08 07:55:32.177: WARN/ResourceType(1537): getEntry failing because entryIndex 187 is beyond type entryCount 123
>   07-08 07:55:32.177: WARN/ResourceType(1537): Failure getting entry for 0x7f0200bb (t=1 e=187) in package 0 (error -2147483647)
>   07-08 07:55:32.187: WARN/ResourceType(1537): getEntry failing because entryIndex 638 is beyond type entryCount 123

Comment: How about letting us see the crash log so we can at least have a clue where to look?

Comment: 'adb logcat' is your friend. It will show you a stack trace, pointing at the exact line and source file that caused the crash.

Comment: Having stacktrace would be helpfull...

Answer (score 1):

If your code above is correct then EmailManager is not an activity and you are calling

```
startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, EmailManager.class));
```

As if it were one.  Are you really trying to start another activity, or just instantiate a new class to be used by the main Activity?

As mentioned in the comments I suggest you actually give us the exception. Walking through (debugging) the code is your friend.

Comment: this is basically an email client which basically displays the retrieved email from gmail ,  which has 3 more files naming account.java , EmailAuthenticator.java,Byte ArraySource.java. All the work is being done by email Managaer.java  . Somebody suggested me to make a main activity file and call this email manager to perform the job . So according to you am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: Like Idistic said, you are trying to start an activity, but according to the code you've provided here the EmailManager class does not extend the Activity class. Activities are really fundamental for understanding how Android works, so you'd better read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html) to learn about it.

Comment: @user832981 well yes, you are trying to start and activity, but your EmailManager class is not an activity like MainActivity is.  I agree with @THelper you need to read up on Activities.  If you are trying to accomplish a long running (as far as android is concerned) task then you should be using something like  AsynchTask to accomplish those types of things.